# Coredata NSPredicate query with multiple conditions

Tags: swift, nspredicate, predicate, searchbar

I have a CoreData database containing the following strings:

- firstName
- lastName
- jobTitle

I have a search bar that calls the following function:

```
    func searchDatabase(input: String) {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Employee> = Employee.fetchRequest()
       let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@ || lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@ || jobTitle CONTAINS[cd] %@", input)
       
        request.predicate = predicate
    
        do {
            LoadData.shared.employeeArray = try LoadData.shared.context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error \(error)")
        }
        
    }
```

At run time I am getting the following error on the predicate line:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x6f7250005a)

How can I fix this? I want the search bar to search the database and the predicate to return values based on first name, last name, or job title.
Thanks

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@ || lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@ || jobTitle CONTAINS[cd] %@", input)` => `NSPredicate(format: "firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@ || lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@ || jobTitle CONTAINS[cd] %@", input, input, input)` You have 3 placeholders (`%@`), so you need 3 variables, even if it's the same one. Imagine, you want `input1, input2, input1`, how would you have written it? And if then you'd want `input1, input1, input2` in that order? Same?

Comment: thanks, Can you elaborate on what you mean with input1, input 1, input2?

Comment: If you have three placeholder %@‘s in your format string, you need to supply three values after the format string, in order, to fill in the placeholders. E.g.  "firstName CONTAINS[cd] %@ || lastName CONTAINS[cd] %@ || jobTitle CONTAINS[cd] %@", firstName, lastName, jobTitle) if input is a string containing three words, you will need to split that string up into separate values first

Comment: I am trying to build the predicate to search all 3 parameters.  For instance, someone can type "CEO" into the search bar and it will see if any of the entries first name, last name or job title matches CEO.  So I don't think I want to split up the input?